# Python: reading a lot of data quickly over and over again

Tags: python, sql

I'm currently doing a project in python that requires a lot of processing. The script reads a local textfile and does a couple of calculations on every line. Every textfile contains about 200 000 lines of data (every line contains a 7 element long, comma separated list with a date and floats) and there are a total of 66 files. On every line i convert the date string to a datetime object and parse the numbers and add them to lists in the script. The data is stored in .txt files in local folders and parsed every time (but my uneducated guess would be something like sql is much more efficient). I want to run calculations on these files over and over again and I was wondering what the best way would be to do this would be.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

How big is the total file size? My guess would be to read them into a string and then convert it to a numpy array and do the calculation. Likely you can read them directly into the numpy from the text file, just google "numpy from text".

Numpy is definitaly better than the normal lists because it's way faster.

Comment: Every text file is about 20 megabytes.